# 1990s? Novels bases on 1930s-style video game?

Tags: story-identification

I am pretty sure I heard about this alternate-universe video game during the '90s or early 2000s. I am not looking for the game itself but a paperback novel - or a series of novels - based on the game. All I can remember of the premise: in the 1920s or '30s the USA breaks up into several warring states which use futuristic 1930s-type aircraft against each other.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This must be [Crimson Skies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimson_Skies), a "dieselpunk" game from 2000.  It was also a tabletop wargame.  There were several [books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimson_Skies#Books) set in the universe as well, that's what you're probably looking for.  The box art shows the kind of "advanced 30s-style" technology, and a zeppelins aircraft carrier.

From TvTropes:

- the series takes place in a Divided States of America universe, which begins after World War I, when a "Regionalist movement" gains popularity in the Union following the outbreak of Spanish influenza pandemic, rallying behind an isolationist platform.

[image: box]

Comment: Thank you, LAK.